# How to get MariaDB slow query logs to show up on RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have a MariaDB instance on RDS which I would like to enable slow query logs for.

Following [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MariaDB.html#USER_LogAccess.MariaDB.Generallog), I've created a paramter group which is assigned to the database.

When I make changes to the parameter group, I can see events logged against the DB "*Finished updating DB parameter group*", which gives me confidence the DB can see the new parameters.

What I can't see, however, is any evidence that the slow query log is made. When I refresh the logs only the default `error/mysql-error-running.log` and its hourly counterparts are there.

I have all logs being passed to Cloudwatch, which can't see any slow query logs either.

After making the change I've hit known slow endpoints, and regardless, I expected to see an empty file at the very least (like we do with the error log).

Is there a step I'm missing? Or an extra big of configuration? Any help gratefully received!

### Contents of custom parameter group

- log_output   FILE
- log_queries_not_using_indexes    1
- long_query_time  1
- slow_query_log   1